# Inverse of a graph in Scheme

Tags: scheme, nested-lists

For example, I have a graph like this:

```
(define graph
 '((a . (d b))
  (b . (c e))
  (c . (e)))
  (d . ())
  (e . ())
```

I have define 3 functions:

`get-all-node`: which returns a list of all nodes in this graph, `(get-all-node graph)` returns `(a b c d e)`

`find-node`: which returns boolean #t or #f if a node is in the nested list or not, for example: `(find-node 'b '(a . (d b)))` return #t, cos if i use memq, it doesnt work at all.

find-inverse-node: which return the first element in the pair that contain a specific node, for example: `(find-inverse-node 'b '(a . (d b)))` will return `(a b)`

I would like to loop through the graph, using each element returned in get-all-node function to find whether that element is in the second part of the pair or not, if it is in, then append it to the list of nodes found.

for example: `(loop-graph graph)` returns `((e b c) (e) (d) (c b) (d a) (b a))`

I tried to do this for so long, but havent been successful. Please help !! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Reasons for closing question include: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance." "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.** See also: Stack Overflow question checklist" You said that you've "tried so long", but there's no code here.   What have you tried so far?  What hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't see a solution in terms of the primitives you describe either (but then, graphs are not my favorite subject). Therefore I'll show you a solution that is quite easy to understand if you know the concept of hash tables. This is Racket, but mutable hash tables also exist in classic Scheme.

Basically, you loop over the initial list. For each (key values...) element, you update a hash map, where the keys are the various elements of values..., and the element added is key. So basically you invert the meaning of key and value.

Since you end up with a hash, this needs to be converted to a list at the end.

Example implementation:

```
(define (inv-graph g)
  (define h (make-hash))
  (map 
   (lambda (x)
     (define k (car x))
     (define v (cadr x))
     (map 
      (lambda (y) 
        (hash-set! h y (cons k (hash-ref h y '())))) 
      v))
   g)
  (hash-map h (lambda (k v) (cons k (list (reverse v))))))
```

such as

```
(inv-graph '((a (d b)) (b (c e)) (c (e)) (d ()) (e ())))
=> '((b (a)) (d (a)) (e (b c)) (c (b)))
```